# Spotfire over function - previous date with multiple categories

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I'd like to calculate a value difference between two rows that is classified by Type and ID and is sorted by a date column. See example data table. Note that column "Calculated" shows the current results, while column "Expected" shows the results I would like to achieve.

```
ID  Type    Date        ValueA  ValueB  ValueC  Calculated  Expected
1   A       8/15/2017   38.11                   
1   A       8/15/2017   78.10                               39.99
1   A       8/22/2017   110.24                              32.14
1   B       8/22/2017           20
1   B       9/16/2017           10
1   A       9/16/2017   101.13                              -9.11
2   C       8/17/2012                   90
2   A       8/18/2012   863.25              
2   B       8/18/2012           15
2   A       8/19/2012   952.35                  89.1        89.1
2   B       8/19/2012           20
```

I tried the following custom expression, but it seems to calculate a difference value only for cases where there is a consecutive date for a given ID.

```
Case  

when [Type]="A" then [Value] - Max([Value]) over (Intersect([ID],Previous([Date])))

else NULL
```

The expression is an attempt to filter to Type "A" for the OVER statement, such that the previous date is the previous date only for values categorized as Type "A". However, it seems to consider the previous date as NULL if is not a consecutive date (i.e. prior day). See "Calculated" in table above for results from this expression.

I also tried to add Type to the Intersect statement, e.g. Intersect([ID],[Type], Previous([Date]), but I get a similar result.

Comment: so value isn't always populated? what's the expected result?

Comment: I updated the post to address your questions. Added multiple value columns that correspond to the different Type's. So, a value column will be populated in a row for only the respective type, else null. I also added a column called "Expected" to show the result that I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

does

```
[value] - max[value] over (intersect([Type],[ID],previous([Date])))
```

give you the calculated column you want

Edit:
I was able to almost match your expected column using this formula (previousperiod instead of just previous), but the first two rows are the same date so it is not an exact match.
[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo6tu.png)

Comment: I updated my post to address your answer. It seems that including both Type and ID in the Intersect statement does not change the result.

Comment: I updated my answer with an image of an approximate answer

Comment: I tried the script and can recover your results on the example table that I provided. Problem is that my actual table is much more complicated than the example that I provided, having a significant number of different "DataType" and intervening "Dates" with numerous NULL values in the column that I'm trying to evaluate. So, the script more-or-less works on the simple table, but not the actual table in my analysis.